# Do you have stats/trends for use of different HyperText Markup Languages?

Tags: html, html5, xhtml, markup

For example: [html-XYZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [xhtml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), [html5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any recent numbers on HTML usage, but [this site](http://nikitathespider.com/articles/ByTheNumbers/fall2008.html#doctypes) has some figures from 2 years ago.

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=557571)'s a small-scale poll of web developers (figures will be skewed since it's from a development site) from 2008 as well.

But it's probably best to just choose your HTML version or doctype by looking at browser support. On new projects, you should just use the latest version of HTML/XHTML that is well-supported across all browsers.

Comment: On the flipside, there is also http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/10-rare-html-tags-you-really-should-know/

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Some nice tips there, but I'm not a big fan of the author's suggested use of the `rel` attribute. The `rel` and `rev` attributes are supposed to define the relationship between the linked document and the current document, not to classify the hyperlink itself. The `class` attribute would be more appropriate and semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible answer**, I will only select my answer as the correct one if up voted 3 times:

- http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/markup_language/all

Also, found these of interest too:

**Javascript Libraries**

- http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all

**client-side programming**

- http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/client_side_language/all

Comment: If you're also interested in server-side languages, then try the TIOBE index.